# Where is the water shutoff in Australian units

Tags: plumbing

I need to be able to turn off the water supply to a unit am working on. However, I have no idea where to look for the water shutoff. (For ex., in most houses in the US (AL), there'd be a little gutter in the ground where I could twist a knob and that would disconnect the water supply to the house)

Where are the water shut-offs in Aussie houses/units ?

Comment: I'm no aussie but have you looked under the kitchen sink?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yes, I have. And it is't under the sink. Turns out none of the units taps were ever connected to a control valve and the only option is to switch it off at the mains !

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to locating shut-off valves, it seems antipodeans are more ruggedly individualistic than the more conformist locales I inhabit.

> Live in a house?
>
> You’ll find the valve near the front of your property ... our valve is located inside the front fence near the boundary with our neighbour. For those of you with larger properties, it might be outside the front fence.
>
> Live in an apartment?
>
> There should be an isolation valve that controls your apartment’s water only. It’s usually under the laundry sink, but also look under the kitchen sink. Look for a tap that appears to be doing nothing. Draw its location and tape it inside the pantry door.

From http://pipeperfection.com.au/plumbing-sydney/water-leak-repair/fact-sheet-turning-household-water/

---

> use the main shutoff valve to turn off the water supply to the entire house. You'll find the main shutoff valve on the inside or outside of your house where the main water supply pipe enters. Turn the valve clockwise to shut it off.

From http://www.powerplumbers.com.au/tips_&_hints.html